React Three Fiber/Drei camera view is stretched vertically when using ScrollControls
I am currently using
"@react-three/drei": "^9.111.3",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.17.5",
"three": "^0.167.1"
I am having an issue with the canvas in r3f. When I implemented ScrollControls on the camera, the environment and all the items in the scene appear to be stretched out vertically, and would return to normal as soon as I scrolled to the bottom. I don't want the stretched effect to happen.
Here is my example of the problem I am encountering.
I've tried using the PerspectiveCamera, reducing the number of pages on the ScrollControls, and scaling the camera down. Switching out the PerspectiveCamera for the OrthographicCamera made the view of all the contents fit the whole page. Other than that, the view is still stretched vertically until I scroll all the way to the bottom.
import * as THREE from "three";
import React from "react";
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  useGLTF,
  OrthographicCamera,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  useAnimations,
  useScroll,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import { GLTF } from "three-stdlib";

type ActionName = "Animation";

interface GLTFAction extends THREE.AnimationClip {
  name: ActionName;
}

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {};
  materials: {};
  animations: GLTFAction[];
};

export default function Camera(props: JSX.IntrinsicElements["group"]) {
  const group = React.useRef<THREE.Group>(null!);
  const cameraRef = useRef<any>(null!);
  const { nodes, materials, animations } = useGLTF(
    "/camera-transformed.glb"
  ) as GLTFResult;
  const { ref, actions } = useAnimations(animations, group);

  console.log(nodes, materials, actions);

  const scroll = useScroll();
  useEffect(() => void (actions.Animation!.reset().play().paused = true), []);
  useFrame(
    () =>
      (actions.Animation!.time =
        actions.Animation!.getClip().duration * scroll.offset)
  );
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      cameraRef.current.aspect = Math.exp(
      scroll.offset - viewport.width / viewport.height
  );
      cameraRef.current.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }, [viewport, scroll.offset]);
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group name="Scene">
        <PerspectiveCamera
          ref={cameraRef}
          name="Camera"
          makeDefault={true}
          far={5000}
          near={0.001}
          position={[-1.154, 17.732, 15.619]}
          scale={[0.007, 0.007, 0.001]}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/camera-transformed.glb");

If you know what might be causing this issue, please let me know!
Thank you!
